# FromBody value get null in web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

this is my post method in apiController

```
[HttpPost]
public String Post([FromBody]String key)
{

    Users ws;
    try
    {
        ws = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(key);
        // return "success "+ key;
        return db.InsertFineInfo(ws);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "ERROR Testing Purposes: " + ex;
    }

}
```

This is part of my model calss.(Users class)there are many attributes but here i have mentioned only few of em with getters and setters

```
{

    private String UserID;
    private String UserName;
    private String UserHeight;
    private String UserWeight;
    private String UserBMI;
    private String RequiredNeutrition;

    public string UserID1
    {
        get
        {
            return UserID;
        }

        set
        {
            UserID = value;
        }
    }
```

i tried to call this post method using postmen .in every attempt i get a null value for key .

[this is how i tried the post method with one header parameter application/json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8L4PAW4RzFqRkl0ZEo0SWRmRkk)

what went wrong ? something wrong with method or the way i try to call it?

Comment: Rather than a link to an image... why not just paste in the JSON you are sending ?

Comment: Can you edit this post and supply the full code for the data structure you're wanting to pass to your web API method

Comment: {  
   "key":{  
      "UserId":"1",
      "UserName":"senura",
      "U_Height":"45",
      "U_Weight":"44",
      "U_BMI":"11",
      "R_Neutro":"44"
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

OK a couple points...

Firstly the JSON your method would be expecting would look like

```
{
   "key": "your string....."
}
```

Secondly the code you have supplied is a bit counter intuitive... Why not simply have

```
[HttpPost]
public String Post([FromBody]Users ws)
{
   ... // Done ?
}
```

You need to publish more code for me to be able to give you a correct answer as to what the JSON would look like that would be accepted by the above method.

In Web API when the parameter comes through as null you can be pretty sure that the JSON sent to the method does not match the JSON generated when you serialize the parameter to a JSON string.

Comment: can i have your email if you don't mind ? then i share

Comment: @blueAko - Just share it in your question above.

Comment: @blueAko sorry not going to give out an email address to a random person on the internet

Comment: @Mick that also true ..sorry mate

Answer (score -1):

You have to model your input as a C# class, and then take that type as an input.
Assuming that you already have a "User" class, with the same properties as the JSON, that you send in the request body:

```
[HttpPost]
public String Post([FromBody]User user)
{
    try
    {

        return db.InsertFineInfo(user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "ERROR Testing Purposes: " + ex;
    }

}
```